# Deployment error Free app running time quota exhausted

Tags: heroku

at=info code=H82 desc="Free app running time quota exhausted" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=covid19data-apii.herokuapp.com request_id=71862c4b-cf84-465e-ac39-bc7afb8b6d8e fwd="59.94.193.113" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

When i deploy my app i get this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have exhausted the quota of free hours ([H82 - Free dyno quota exhausted](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h82-free-dyno-quota-exhausted)) so your app can no longer run.
You have 2 options:

- register a valid Credit Card to obtain an additional 450 hours (total of 1000): note that the Credit Card will not be charged, these are still free hours
- upgrade to a paid tier

Comment: How can i check how much free dyno I have left?

Comment: In the Heroku Dashboard -> Billing